# Match column name with data from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have dynamically created a temp table #temp1 that create column dynamically based on a json string. The table will look like as below

#temp1

| ID | Field | FRUIT | VEGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Field1 | A | B |
| 2 | Field2 | C | D |

I would like to fill in the value column only in result table based on the #temp1 table, the field and type_id is already filled beforehand

result table

| ID | field | type_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Field1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | Field1 | 2 | B |
| 3 | Field2 | 1 | C |
| 4 | Field2 | 2 | D |

where the type_id can get from another table that specified the type and its id

type table

| ID | type_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FRUIT |
| 2 | 2 | VEGE |

The type table will have many different types in it, I just list out the only two that is used in this question only.

Please help!

my attempt query:

```
update B
        set B.value = ' value B.column_name in #result match with'
        from result_table B
        inner join type_table D
        on D.type = 'column name in result_table'
```

Comment: Please kindly include your attempt query. And the logic required to get to the required result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `Dynamic Query` as your column is dynamic

```
declare @sql       nvarchar(max),
        @case_stmt nvarchar(max)

-- form the case statement
select @case_stmt = STRING_AGG ('WHEN ''' + type + ''' THEN t1.' + quotename(t.type), char(13))
from   typ t
where  exists 
       (
           select *
           from   result r 
           where  t.type_id = r.type_id
       )

-- Print out for insepction
print @case_stmt

-- form final query
select @sql = 'update r' + char(13)
            + 'set value = CASE t.type' + char(13)
            + @case_stmt + char(13)
            + 'END'+ char(13)
            + 'from   result r' + char(13)
            + 'inner join #temp1 t1 on r.Field = t1.Field' + char(13)
            + 'inner join typ t     on r.type_id = t.type_id' + char(13)
-- Print out for insepction
print @sql            

exec (@sql);

select *
from  result
```

note : `char(13)` is new line. It helps to do simple formatting of the query

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2dcb389a009d244013cd855ebd703ba0)

Comment: Since the table type will usually be large, is there any alternative not to use case when ?? Maybe just return the matched value between the column name and type

Comment: `JOIN` `typ` to `result` table for the `@case_stmt` or use `EXISTS()`

Comment: I think your answer is what I expected, but I'm having this error : Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: can you also show the query for JOIN typ to result table for the @case_stmt or use EXISTS() ??

Comment: added `JOIN` to `@case_stmt`

Comment: You get the collation conflict because you have table with different collation. You can cast  it from one to another using `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`

Comment: Changed to use `EXISTS()` checking as using `JOIN` will result in duplicates

Answer (score 1):

If it’s true that the result table will already have an existing record that already contains field and type_id, like you mention, then I think you could try this:

```
UPDATE B
SET B.value = 
    CASE WHEN
        D.type = ‘FRUIT’
    THEN
        T.FRUIT
    WHEN
        D.type = ‘VEGE’
    THEN T.VEGE
    END
FROM result_table B
INNER JOIN #temp1 T ON T.field = B.field
INNER JOIN type_table D on D.type_id = B.type_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bed087b6599ad2e0623b1198efcff845

However, this will require that you had an additional CASE statement per each type_id you wish to update in the future.

If it’s possible for you to change the way in which the temp table is being created and populated from the json object, then please consider structuring your temp table like this instead:

| ID | Field | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | field1 | FRUIT | A |
| 2 | field1 | VEGE | B |
| 3 | field2 | FRUIT | C |
| 4 | field2 | VEGE | D |

Then your SQL to update the value column could simplify to this:

```
UPDATE B
SET B.Value = T.value
FROM result_table B
INNER JOIN type_table D on D.type_id = B.type_id
INNER JOIN #temp1 T ON T.Field = B.field AND T.type = D.type
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87a2b650c646ea0be5e65fe1d7012227